# Selenium Python: problem in getting proper attribute and find product through created loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, attributes

```
class XkomAddProductToBacket(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chrome/chromedriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("https://www.x-kom.pl/")
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

def testCheckTotalValueProducts(self):
    driver = self.driver
    # 1. Kliknij  w pole wyszukiwania.

    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Czego szukasz?"]')
    # 2. Wpisz żądaną wartość.

    search_field.send_keys(search_value + Keys.RETURN)

    # 3. Kliknij w przycisk lupy w celu wywołania wyszukiwania.

    search_submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.apKoa")
    search_submit.click()

    # 4,5 Wybierz pozadany produkt z dostepnej listy i dodaj go do koszyka.

    product_container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='listing-container']")
    button_enabled = driver.find_element_by_class_name("geHfky")
    button_disabled = button_enabled.get_attribute("disabled")

    for product in product_container:
        if not product(button_disabled):
            p = button_enabled(product)
            p.click()


    # 6. Kliknij w przycisk "Przejdź do koszyka".

    go_to_basket = driver.find_element_by_class_name("jipXcf")
    go_to_basket.click()


    sleep(10)
```

**Website**: x-kom.pl

I would like to move through all visible products after find "laptop" value on search engine and find product  with available button without "disabled" button and then add the proper that to basket.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no method like contains on a webelement. You need use another find_element_xx on the `product` weblement` and see if a child element with certain properties exists or not

Comment: Could you write me solution to my code?  I would be grateful for your help. :)

Comment: I've attached more images and changed my code

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.get("https://www.x-kom.pl/szukaj?q=laptop")

# hide chat button since it overlaps with add to cart button
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('ekQbox')[0].remove();");


for laptop in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("eWIMMl"):
    if (btn:=laptop.find_element_by_tag_name("button")) and btn.get_attribute("disabled"):
        print("Item not avaliable")
    else:
        btn.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("kaXDUC").click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

.get_attribute method is false if attribute doesn't exsist

Comment: Could you adjust the way of a solution to my code? I set up my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating all over elements just correct the xpath and it will only return the enabled elements. and then take the appropriate action on the elements.

I just replaced this line of code instead of the code you provided -

```
button_enabled = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@title='Dodaj do koszyka' and not(@disabled)]")

print(len(button_enabled))
for product in button_enabled:
        i = 1 + i
        print("product is available", i)
```

It return me output as -

```
26 
product is available 1 
product is available 2 
product is available 3 
          : 
          : 
          : 
product is available 25 
product is available 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got that in the console after run execution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJSnH.png)

Code snippet:

```
product_container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='listing-container']")
button_enabled = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@title='Dodaj do koszyka' and not(@disabled)]")
button_disabled = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@title='Dodaj do koszyka']")

    for product in product_container:
        if not product(button_disabled):
            p = button_enabled(product)
            p.click()
```

Comment: What solution do you propose?